# The first eigenvalue of Laplacian

Tags: partial-differential-equations

It's well known that for any bounded domain $\Sigma$, there exist unique $\lambda_\Sigma >0$
  and nonnegative $\varphi\in H_0^1(\Sigma)$ such that
  \begin{equation}\label{Eq-La-Bel-op}
    \left\{
      \begin{aligned}
        &-\Delta\varphi=\lambda_\Sigma\varphi
        \quad\mbox{in }\Sigma, \\
        &\varphi=0 \quad\quad\quad\quad~\mbox{on } \partial\Sigma,\\
      \end{aligned}
     \right.
  \end{equation}
  where $\Delta$ is the Laplace operator and $\lambda_\Sigma$ is the first eigenvalue of it.

Question: For any $\varepsilon>0$ small, does there eixist some smooth domain  $\Omega$ such that $\Sigma\subsetneq\Omega$ and 
$\lambda_{\Sigma}\leq\lambda_{\Omega}+\varepsilon$?

Comment: Are you sure this is what you need? Because there is a trivial answer; just take $\Omega$ equal to a translate of $\Sigma$.

Comment: A translate of $\Sigma$ is not a superset of $\Sigma$.

Comment: How about $\Omega$ is not a planar domain? e.g., $\Omega$ is a subdomain of unit sphere. (There is a result: If $\Omega$ is a planar domain, then $\lambda_{(\alpha\Omega)}=\frac{\lambda_{\Omega}}{\alpha^2}$)

Comment: OH sorry, that symbol made me think that $\Sigma \not\subset \Omega$.

Comment: Just scaling your domain only satisfied your condition of $\Sigma\subsetneq \Omega$ if it is star shaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One answer to this question is that you could try to use continuity of eigenvalues with respect to changes of the domain. I haven't looked at the proofs (they aren't in the reference I use anyway), but in Antoine Henrot's book *Extremum problems for eigenvalues of elliptic operators*, Section 2.3.3 deals with this (and Section 2.3.5 tells you about differentiability). The results are approximately (all sets lying in a fixed compact set)

1. if $\Sigma$ is convex and $\Omega_n$ are convex sets tending to $\Sigma$ in Hausdorff distance, then $\lambda_k(\Omega_n)\to \lambda_k(\Sigma)$.
2. If $\Omega_n$ are uniformly Lipschitz and converging to $\Sigma$ in Hausdorff distance, then $\lambda_k(\Omega_n)\to \lambda_k(\Sigma)$
3. If $\Omega_n\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ such that the number of connected components of the complement is uniformly bounded, and converging to $\Sigma$ in Hausdorff distance, then $\lambda_k(\Omega_n)\to \lambda_k(\Sigma)$.

Depending on the regularity and connectedness properties of your set $\Sigma$ (and the dimension), this could answer your problems. I am not aware of any necessary conditions for continuity, but of course there might be some.